# How can I share my secondary monitor to a remote system as if it were directly connected to it?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, monitor, display-manager

**Introduction**

A laptop typically has either a VGA or HDMI connector as a display port, and some laptops even have both. If you connect a secondary monitor to this laptop, you can easily drag and drop any window from the primary to the secondary monitor and work seamlessly.

This functionality applies to all **workspaces** as well.

**Situation**

Through *Remmina* is possible get remote access from a Host laptop **to** a target laptop - for simplicity it in the same LAN - in peace. The situation is that the target laptop does not have a secondary monitor and the host laptop has a secondary monitor. Therefore:

```
Host Laptop --- --- --->>> Target Laptop 
1 Secondary    Remmina      0 Secondary  
 Monitor                      Monitor
```

**Goal**

I want need to know if is possible execute a command in the target laptop to **cheat** the OS to indicate that it has connected a secondary monitor based on the same settings than the one connected in the Host laptop. Of course, there is no a secondary monitor connected in the Target Laptop.

Therefore the "fake" scenario should be the same as *if exists two identical displays/monitors and each one is connected to each laptop*. Thus in the Host laptop is possible drag and drop any window to the secondary monitor - it without matter if really the Target does not have a real secondary monitor connected.

Is possible accomplish this goal? I need this command being generic or portable, it to be executed in Ubuntu and Fedora.